# mysqli_num_rows is no working?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do if, which will check if value is stored in the mysql database but I do not understand why it does not work. Is this how you can save it?

```
$przelew_nrkonta = $_POST['przelew_nrkonta'];

if (mysqli_num_rows($przelew_nrkonta) <= 0) { ... }
```

My all code:

```
$przelew_nrkonta = $_POST['przelew_nrkonta'];
$przelew_pieniadze = $_POST['przelew_pieniadze'];

$sql1 = sprintf("UPDATE kontabankowe SET pieniadze = pieniadze + '%s' WHERE nrkonta= '%s'",
    mysqli_real_escape_string($polaczenie, $przelew_pieniadze),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($polaczenie, $przelew_nrkonta));
$sql2 = sprintf("UPDATE kontabankowe SET pieniadze = pieniadze - '%s' WHERE nrkonta = '%s'",
    mysqli_real_escape_string($polaczenie, $przelew_pieniadze),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($polaczenie, $_SESSION['nrkonta']));


if ($polaczenie->connect_errno != 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $polaczenie->connect_errno;
} else {

    if (mysqli_num_rows($przelew_nrkonta) <= 0) {
        echo "zly numer konta";
        //header('Location: errors/error2.php');
    } else {

        if ($_SESSION['pieniadze'] < $przelew_pieniadze || $_SESSION['pieniadze'] <= 0) {
            header('Location: errors/error1.php');
        } else {
            if ($polaczenie->query($sql1) && ($polaczenie->query($sql2)) === TRUE) {
                header('Location: errors/favorably.php');
            } else {
                header('Location: errors/error3.php');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the SQL statement you are counting the rows for?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: I am trying to check if such a value is passed on the html form exists in mysql

Comment: Please start with a basic php mysql tutorial. Its very important to get the basic understanding before proceeding to create a system/app etc.

Answer (score 0):

The input of the function mysqli_num_rows should be a mysqli_query.

Comment: Still can't see where you are actually executing your SQL.